# Как сделать наблюдение над JSON результатом в VUE JS и применить к нему методы

Tags: css, vue.js, asp.net-core

Всем привет!
Мне нужно сделать наблюдение над JSON результатом

```
<div id="app">
<div class="mainblock">
    <div class="row">

        <a  class="blc-blue blc blc-medium blc-radius" asp-controller="Blocks" asp-action="ServiceDesk">

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <img class="blc-image" src="~/images/calls.png">
                <h4 class="textblock1">Заявки</h4>
                <span class="textblock1-line1"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="textblock1-block1">
                <h4 class="textblock1-pokaz1">открытые:</h4>
                <h4 class="textblock1-pokaz2">просроченные:</h4>
                <div class="textblock1-block11">

                    <h3 class="textblock1-pokaz3">{{openToday.total}}</h3>
                    <h3 class="textblock1-pokaz4">{{loseToday.total}}</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        openToday: [],
        urlGetList: '/Elastic/GetData',
        loseToday: [],
        urlGetList2: '/Elastic/GetData2',
        allThings: [],
        urlGetList3: '/Elastic/GetData3',
        visible: {},
    methods: {
        get_data() {
            fetch(this.urlGetList)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.openToday = json.hitsMetadata;
                })
            fetch(this.urlGetList2)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.loseToday = json.hitsMetadata;
                })
            fetch(this.urlGetList3)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.allThings = json.hitsMetadata;
                })
        },


    updated() {
        this.get_data()
    },
    created() {
        this.get_data()
    }
})
```

Здесь мне надо что бы наблюдатель смотрел результат на `{{openToday.total}}` и менял на другой класс.

Например, если там результат возвращается 20 то надо поменять фон блока

Comment: "...Мне нужно сделать..." - делайте и только после этого, если возникнут проблемы, приходите сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Вам не нужен никакой наблюдатель. В первой же главе документации по vue рассказывается про реактивность.

Comment: @AK далеко не во всех случаях это работает. То есть, если нужно просто отобразить значение измененное, то ок, но если нужно при изменении триггерить метод, то только вотчером. Я других способов не знаю. Если знаешь, поделись, будет круто. В доке про это не видел ничего. На самом деле не такой очевидно простой вопрос автор задал.

Comment: @AlexSazonov Спасибо за поддержку, я пробовал watch сделать но дальше не смог идти, вотчером надо подумать! Спасибо

Comment: @AlexSazonov Топикстартер ни слова не сказал, что ему нужно триггерить метод, в задании как раз про отобразить.

Comment: @AlexSazonov А, нет, я невнимателен: прям в заголовке крупными буквами. А вот в тексте ничего про это не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Здесь мне надо что бы наблюдатель смотрел результат на {{openToday.total}} и менял на другой класс. Например, если там результат возвращается 20 то надо поменять фон блока.

Нет, в этой ситуации вам не нужен `watch`. Класс меняется в зависимости от вычисляемого свойства.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    openToday: '',
  },
  computed: {
    // Вычисляемое свойство будет применено к тегу
    // в зависимости от величины `openToday.total`.
    totalClass() {
      return {
        'alert-success': this.openToday.total < 20,
        'alert-warning': this.openToday.total >= 20 && this.openToday.total <= 30,
        'alert-danger': this.openToday.total > 30,
        'alert-secondary': !this.openToday.total
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      // Импровизация получения данных ч/з `fetch` метод.
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.openToday = {
          total: "500"
        }
      }, 2000)
    },
    setData(num) {
      this.openToday = {
        total: num
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.example {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.alert {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.alert-success {
  color: #155724;
  background-color: #d4edda;
  border-color: #c3e6cb;
}

.alert-warning {
  color: #856404;
  background-color: #fff3cd;
  border-color: #ffeeba;
}

.alert-danger {
  color: #721c24;
  background-color: #f8d7da;
  border-color: #f5c6cb;
}

.alert-secondary {
  color: #383d41;
  background-color: #e2e3e5;
  border-color: #d6d8db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" class="example" @click="setData(19)">Установить 19</button>
  <button type="button" class="example" @click="setData(30)">Установить 30</button>
  <button type="button" class="example" @click="setData(40)">Установить 40</button>
  <span class="example alert" :class="totalClass">{{ openToday.total || 'Результат загружается ...' }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример. Посмотри что у тебя не так. дальше разбираться будем.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    inp: '',
    res: '',
  },
  methods: {
    doOnChange() {
      this.res = this.inp;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    inp: {
      handler: 'doOnChange',
      deep: true // это если многоуровневая структура
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="inp"> Начни писать в поле
  <p>Изменяется из watch: {{ res }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alex Sazonov Спасибо Вам тоже за помощь